# How do you retrieve User Defined Runtime Attributes in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

On my XCode storyboard I have a custom image view (called CustomImageButton).  There is a section about User Defined Runtime Attributes:

[image: User Defined Runtime Attributes]

I've seen a couple of examples about how to retrieve these values in Objective-C but can't work out how to convert to Xamarin C#.  The code I'm using is:

```
class CustomImageButton : UIImageView
{
    public CustomImageButton(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
        NSObject objType = ValueForKey(new NSString("bgType"));
        if (objType == null)
            // Do something here
    }

    public override NSObject ValueForUndefinedKey(NSString key)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

However, it always goes into the undefined key part and returns null.  How can I retrieve the string 'Transparent' for the key 'bgType'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Custom (C#-based) UI class, add a property for your **custom** User Defined Runtime Attribute.

```
[Connect]
private NSString Stack { 
    get {
        return (NSString)GetNativeField ("Stack");
    }
    set {
        SetNativeField ("Stack", value);
    }
}
```

This will in turn auto-generate the property in your ObjC custom class header file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *Stack;
```

Defined your attribute value:

[image]

When the xib or storyboard is loaded, this property gives the custom attribute a place to be stored for future reference.

Now you can access this value via `ValueForKey`:

```
partial void OnBottonUpInside (CustomButton sender) {
        NSString value = (NSString)sender.ValueForKey(new NSString("Stack"));
        Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Output Example:

```
2016-02-03 08:27:51.666 keyvalue[46492:2538387] OverFlow
```

Of course, I could have defined the property as public and just access it that way:

```
partial void OnBottonUpInside (CustomButton sender)
{
    Console.WriteLine (sender.Stack);
}
```

Note: Normally in ObjC you would just define this as a strong property, but Xamarin does not define it that way, but the result is the "same":

```
@property (strong) NSString *Stack;
```

Comment: Very concise!  Many thanks.  With the first bit I made the change in Visual Studio and it didn't update in XCode, but when I opened the file in Xamarin Studio on the Mac and saved it it update XCode as you've said.  May have been a one off.

Comment: `GetNativeField()` and `SetNativeField()` appear to be deprecated now

Comment: @Felipe They flagged those two apis as `Obsolete` due to if you do not maintain references, you will leak and/or crash. You of course can still use the underlaying ObjC calls: `object_getInstanceVariable` and `object_setInstanceVariable` to achieve the same results.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for but I'm wondering whether you can shed some light on how to actually access those underlying ObjC calls. I've been unsuccessful @SushiHangover by trying to creatively work it out myself as well as searching the web for clues.

Comment: Although I figured it out eventually, still curious to know the answer to my query just for future reference :)

Answer (score 0):

@SushuHangover's response is correct and still works. However, if you want to avoid the deprecated GetNativeField() & SetNativeField() methods, then this would be the change that has worked for me:

```
[Connect]
private NSObject Stack
{
    get
    {
        return ValueForKey((NSString)"Stack");
    }
    set
    {
        SetValueForKey(value, (NSString)"Stack");
    }
}
```